# Resolve "ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'" within an imported module

Tags: python, string, module, format

I'm using a python toolbox which has recently been ported to Python 3.x (https://github.com/GEMScienceTools/gmpe-smtk).

The toolbox is working smoothly, but when I try to extract the produced data as before in the Python 2.7 version using the command `resid1.pretty_print("C:/Python37/PGAandSA_Appendix.csv", sep=",")`, I'm greeted with the following error `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`.

The error is said to correspond to line 705 of an imported python module. The line of code is :

`For key in event["Sites"].__dict__:
                data.append("{:.4f}".format(getattr(event["Sites"], key)[i]))`

The module is found in the following directory: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smtk-3.5.0-py3.7.egg\smtk\residuals\gmpe_residuals.py`

I'm assuming I will have to edit the code within this line. If anyone could explain the modification I will have to make and why it would be much appreciated. I've been made aware editing an imported python module is dangerous, so elaboration of as to why would also be helpful (surely I can just change the code back to the original or use a fresh install?).

Thanks!

Comment: Change the format string to `"{}"` so that it no longer tries to format the value as a float.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work? The error  `IndexError: list index out of range` is produced following this? Does the format string modification mean it should look like `For key in event["Sites"].__dict__:
                data.append("{}".format(getattr(event["Sites"], key)[i]))` instead?

Comment: It sounds like the code requires`getattr(event["Sites"], key)` to be numeric then.  So the question is, what does that expression evaluate to?

Comment: My apologies I'm new to python, but I'm guessing you're asking what does `getattr(event["Sites"], key)` represent or do in the imported module?

Comment: The code expects a float, which it formats to have four decimal places, and then extracts the digit (or decimal point) corresponding to position `i`.  The value isn't float - that's the cause of the original error - and its string representation is shorter than `i` - the cause of the new error.  So what is the value?  Maybe add a line just before like `print(repr(getattr(event["Sites"], key)))` to see.